# How can I prevent Visual Studio from opening files in new tab-groups

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 sometimes opens file in a separate tab group. I have no idea why and this is perfectly useless and causes the work to put the file from the new tab into the single tab that I use for files.

While searching for a solution I found a setting "Group tabs by project/path" which howver is disabled. I also wonder why this setting is not settable.

[image]

How can I stop VS from opening files in separate tabs. And optionally: is the setting above related and how can I change it?

Comment: tabs are meant for files, so obviously a new file needs to be opened in a new tab. Which IDE doesn't do that?

Comment: maybe i should say "tab group"

Comment: It groups tabs for documents that it opens by itself, keeping them separate from the ones you explicitly opened.  For example by single-stepping into them while debugging.  That's a feature, makes it easier to find the tabs you are likely to want to close.  Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > untick "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab" to disable.

Comment: That looks very good, unticked that and assume I wont see that anymore. thank you so much Hans.

Comment: I found "Group tabs by project/path" to be disabled, as in the screenshot. To make the checkbox editable, I changed "Set tab layout" (in the screenshot) from "Top" to "Left". This let me change the checkbox, such that I then put "Set tab layout" back to its original "Top" value.